# How to clip only an object ( not all sence ) use glClipPlane?

Tags: opengl, clipping

The question is as the title. If not use glClipPlane, please suggest me a solution for clip a 3D Object ( like Sphere or Torus... ).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for glClipPlane to work you have to Enable it using glEnable();

If you want to clip just one object your code should look like this:

```
//draw some stuff
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE_1);
glClipPlane(...);
//draw clipped object
glDisable(GL_CLIP_PLANE_1);
//draw some stuff
```